# Seaborne Bar Plot Median Estimator Error

Tags: pandas, seaborn

When I plot a seaborn barplot using a median estimator, i get the below error. Seems to work for other estimators (e.g. sum). What am I missing?

```
j = sns.barplot(x='category', y='sales', data=perf, estimator=median)
for item in j.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(90)
plt.show()

NameError: name 'median' is not defined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Import it:

```
from numpy import median
```

Or

```
import numpy as np
j = sns.barplot(x='category', y='sales', data=perf, estimator=np.median)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all you need to import Numpy module:

```
import numpy as np
```

2. You need to write:

```
estimator = np.median
```

instead of

```
estimator = median
```